# Embed Java applet through URL data

Tags: java, html, applet, base64

I'm trying to explore URL data capabilities to embed in HTML Java applet.

The documentation, for HTML tags to instantiation a java applet [1](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html), don't exclude this option but I don't seem to be able to to this.

I have different variations of HTML tags values using (object and applet) and what I think came close to my goal was this:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="100" height="100">
  <param name="archive" value="data:application/java-archive;base64,BASE64_OF_JAR"/>
  <param name="code" value="test.class"/>
  <h1>not working</h1>
</object>
```

This variation result in an IlegalArgumentException with text "name". I check this clicking on the Error Icon on the Browser. On The java console the whole stack trace is:

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter.setProgressFilter(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.setupProgress(Unknown Source)
        at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Does anyone have an idea about how to do this or if it's not possible?**

PS: There's an example of how to embed an JNLP in HTML by Oracle [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html)

Comment: Have to admit I did not read the post carefully the other day & missed that last link.   Intriguing that a JNLP can be base 64 encoded..

Comment: What happens if you swap `data:application/java-archive` with `data:application/x-java-archive`?

Comment: It's the same exception.
The plugin handler doesn't seem to recognize the DATA URL, it would be nice to see the source code of the plugin :)
The full exception: http://pastebin.com/ddsDSTQg

Comment: Could you edit that stacktrace into the question?  Also use code formatting on it.  BTW - I was trying to set up a local test here that resulted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498256/why-the-npe-in-this-code).  SNAFU!  ;)

Comment: well, you have now learnt that "doesn't exclude" doesn't imply "does include" :P

Comment: BTW - can you give us the base 64 text of both a (very simple) applet class and the Jar?

Comment: A DummyApplet.class base64 http://pastebin.com/Jjmz5U4h; A DummyApplet.jar base64 http://pastebin.com/8fFDCQuF and the source code http://pastebin.com/3BaLijWj Thanks

Comment: I think I found my answer in the source code http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/plugin2/applet/Applet2Manager.java.html no base64 references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.3.1) for OBJECT element allows inline data embed through [URL DATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and the Applet instantiation [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/applet.html) from Oracle also allows this. The tests performed show the Java browser plugin (from Oracle), and the available source code from [Java SE 6](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/), shows that the implementation doesn't support it.

In this case, doesn't seem to matter if the browser support it, because the resource handling of resources reference in the Object/Applet HTML Element are performed by the browser plugin.

An alternative would be to be use applet deserialization, serialized through URL DATA, using the OBJECT attribute of [APPLET element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.4). As mentioned in the HTML4 specification, there is no active support for APPLET and OBJECT attribute, and JRE doesn't seem to support Object deserialization from URL DATA too.

In a nutshell, JRE doesn't support base64 deserialization in the CODE, OBJECT and ARCHIVE HTML attributes.

There is also a BUG regarding URL DATA support in JRE1.4.1 that wasn't fulfilled [Bug ID: 4756961](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4756961).

The results of my tests with JRE7 in a 64 bits Windows machine are the following:

- Passing a JAR through URL DATA to ARCHIVE attribute results in an IllegalArgumentException in Applet2Manager.loadJarFiles();
- Passing a class through URL DATA to CODE attribute results in a ClassNotFoundException in Applet2ClassLoader.findClass();
- Passing a serialized applet through URL DATA to OBJECT attribute results in a FileNotFoundException in Plugin2ClassLoader.getResourceAsResource().

Comment: excellent answer, well-researched with useful links. Wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it is allowable by HTML standards, JREs typically do not understand base64 encoded data.