# Why the NPE using static method of DatatypeConverter?

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, base64, type-conversion

I have stared at this short code too long, and cannot for the life of me see how it can throw a `NullPointerException` on line 6.  Why the NPE?

```
class ConvertTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] b = "Ha".getBytes("UTF-8");
        System.out.println("bytes: " + b.length);
        javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(b);  // NPE!
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
bytes: 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:547)
        at ConvertTest.main(ConvertTest.java:6)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Update

While many of the bug reports are pointing to a 1.7 variant, I was astonished to see that Eclipse is configured to use `1.6.0_32` & TextPad has found a version of `1.6.0-b105` (didn't even realize that was installed!).

Both JREs fail with that NPE.

Comment: Whoa! Andrew Thompson is asking a question :D

Comment: I am not getting any NPE. output bytes: 2. Ran exact same code in Netbeans.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  You don't think I build up that 50K rep. for nothing do you?  I use it as bounties on my questions.  ;)

Comment: @Nambari Thanks.  I'll look more closely at the local environment.

Comment: I didn't get a NPE either. Maybe you need to update your JRE.

Comment: Could it be related to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-249)?

Comment: looking inside the jdk source, the DatatypeConverter uses an internal impl.  this impl being null is the only thing which could cause NPE.  this seems to agree with @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas's suggestion that the problem is related to confused/conflicting jaxb libraries.

Comment: I would wonder which version of Java you are using (and which update) and which version of JAXB you are using..

Comment: It works on latest version of JRE7 on a 64bits windows machine. It returns: SGE=

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as though there are bugs in JAXB within JDK7 right now, as evidenced by this issue on Camel:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-4893

which ultimately links to this issue https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/issues/860 in the JAXB project on java.net.

I'm not entirely sure if you are running into this same thing or not, but perhaps try using JDK6 with the latest JAXB version there and see if the same NPE happens or not.

Answer (score 2):

Without the specifics of the environment I cannot be certain this is the case but if you are using JAXB RI then it's possible that you are running into the issue described by this JAXB bug: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-761.

While the bug doesn't specifically address the issue you were having (it is related to the `parseDate` method), the root cause may be the same.  It was detected in version 2.2.1 of JAXB but may have been there beforehand in 2.1.x versions, and JAXB 2.1.1 appears to be the most recent release integrated into 1.6 (integrated in 1.6u14).

The issue states that it was resolved with JAXB 2.2.4, which was integrated into 1.7.

*Additional note* - a related issue was documented regarding a NPE for `parseBoolean` when attempting to use with 1.6u31 which may be of interest (though little help, the description is very short): http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-902.  This suggest this could still be an ongoing issue depending on if you are using RI or another JAXB implementation.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String printBase64Binary( byte[] val ) {
    return theConverter.printBase64Binary( val );
}
```

> JAXB Providers are required to call the setDatatypeConverter api at
>   some point before the first marshal or unmarshal operation (perhaps
>   during the call to JAXBContext.newInstance). This step is necessary to
>   configure the converter that should be used to perform the print and
>   parse functionality

Try setting the converter first

```
/**
     * This method is for JAXB provider use only.
     * <p>
     * JAXB Providers are required to call this method at some point before
     * allowing any of the JAXB client marshal or unmarshal operations to
     * occur.  This is necessary to configure the datatype converter that 
     * should be used to perform the print and parse conversions.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Calling this api repeatedly will have no effect - the 
     * DatatypeConverterInterface instance passed into the first invocation is 
     * the one that will be used from then on.
     * 
     * @param converter an instance of a class that implements the 
     * DatatypeConverterInterface class - this parameter must not be null.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the parameter is null
     */
    public static void setDatatypeConverter( DatatypeConverterInterface converter ) {
        if( converter == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( 
                Messages.format( Messages.CONVERTER_MUST_NOT_BE_NULL ) );
        } else if( theConverter == null ) {
            theConverter = converter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to make this call yourself.  the jaxb provider should be doing it.

Comment: But maybe the jaxb provider is not properly initialized / configured at this point.