# NullPointerException when using DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, type-conversion

Am using parseHexBinary method of javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter but its giving me

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(DatatypeConverter.java:310)
        at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

when I use with Java version 1.6.0_01 but works fine with Java v1.6.0.05 in Eclipse.

Is there any other way I can do this in v1.6.0_01? Otherwise I will have to upgrade.

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
          String str1 = "F3F0";
          Charset charset = Charset.forName("Cp037");
          String s;

               byte b[] = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str1);
               s = new String(b,charset); //cbuf.toString();
               System.out.println("String is: " + s);

      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }    
}
```

Comment: @Duncan Jones, added the code.. hope there should not be any issue?

Comment: Looks fine to me - can't see why that would trigger a NPE in `parseHexBinary`.

Comment: May be its a bug in 1.6.0_01 Java version - found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498256/why-the-npe-using-static-method-of-datatypeconverter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a custom func like this

```
byte[] parseHex(String str) {
    byte[] a = new BigInteger(str, 16).toByteArray();
    if (a.length != str.length() / 2) {
        a = Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 1, a.length);
    }
    return a;
}
```