# Modify classes in third party Java libraries declared as maven dependency (shall or not and is it legal)

Tags: java, maven, class, build, dependencies

Is it acceptable to modify specific class implementation of third party Java library declared as maven dependency, how and to make include this customized library in build?

The case is, we are trying to use *jjwt library* to generate and validate JWT tokens, but *io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec* throw the following expection:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:547)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.encode(Base64Codec.java:21)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64UrlCodec.encode(Base64UrlCodec.java:22)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.base64UrlEncode(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:350)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:296)
    ...
```

This expection is thrown due the bug in *DatatypeConverter* when fed with too long string in Java 6 compatible environment. However, we can't change the JRE environment on our server due certain  restrictions, and wouldn't want to introduce another JWT library either.

Problem could probably be solved by changing the simple implementation of *io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec*

```
16    package io.jsonwebtoken.impl;
17
18    public class Base64Codec extends AbstractTextCodec {
19
20    public String encode(byte[] data) {
21        return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(data);
22    }
23
24    @Override
25    public byte[] decode(String encoded) {
26        return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encoded);
27    }
28}
```

To use Apache Commons Codec library instead.

First, does Apache Licence version 2.0 allow such modifications to library, when end product is sold to customer, and second, how could we include the customized library in our build in an convenient manner?

Comment: Not a lawyer, but ASL2.0 is very permissive and I'd be shocked if it didn't allow you to do what you described. I've also seen this done in many, many commercial products. But, before all that, why not submit a pull request to jjwt fixing the issue officially instead? This is why open source exists in the first place.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but you may find it simpler to call [javax.xm.bind.DatatypeConverter.setDatatypeConverter(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#setDatatypeConverter(javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterInterface)) with a new `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl` instance. You will have to put this code in the `java.xml.bind` package. From what I can see, this known issue is an initialisation problem rather than a function of the length of the string.

Comment: See also [Why the NPE using static method of DatatypeConverter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498256/why-the-npe-using-static-method-of-datatypeconverter)